# preserve recipients in the sendgrid API

Tags: sendgrid

I'm sending an email to multiple recipients using the sendgrid API !

```
<?php


$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('API_KEY');

$email
    ->addTo(array('first@mail.com','second@mail.com'..))
    ->setFrom('my@mail.com')
    ->setSubject('Subject goes here')
    ->setText('Hello World!')
    ->setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>')
;

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

Now, I wanna know if there is any way to hide the second email in the "To" header for the first email?

Comment: Set the second email to bcc field?

Comment: @Zuzlx I don't wanna use the bcc filed, is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SMTP API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) for mail-merge type functionality.

Using [sendgrid-php](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#addsmtpapito), that looks like:

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email
    ->addSmtpapiTo('foo@bar.com')
    ->addSmtpapiTo('another@another.com', 'Mike Bar')
;
$sendgrid->send($email);
```

Or for an array:

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$emails = array("foo@bar.com", "Brian Bar <bar@example.com>", "other@example.com");
$email->setSmtpapiTos($emails);
$sendgrid->send($email);
```